# In Google Apps Script action handler, how to get value of a selection input?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Documentation shows examples of creating a SelectionInput item: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input

**Question**: How to read value of SelectionInput in an action handler? Like:

```js
var dropdown = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
  .setTitle("Status")
  .setFieldName("dd_status")
  .addItem("A", 1, status == 1)
  .addItem("B", 2, status == 2)
  .addItem("C", 3, status == 3)
  .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
  .setFunctionName("handleStatusDropdownChange").setParameters({'thread_id': thread_id}));
```

Now, how to access `dd_status` in `handleStatusDropdownChange`? It does not seem to appear in parameters, when the handler is defined like:

```js
function handleStatusDropdownChange(e) {
    var parameters = e.parameters;
}
```

Where is it?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))`?

Comment: For some reason, it does not work!

Comment: This one does:  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); I know. This seems to be somehow ureliable. I have tried it before, switched to strackdriver logging that does not seem to work for me and now back to Logger and voila!

Comment: @Rubén yes, why?

Comment: @Marcin Because others tried to create others kinds of script and the cardservice only works for gmail addons.

Comment: How ridiculous they don't have sample code for this

Answer (score 1):

All the input values are being held inside the event object passed to the handler function.

```
function handleStatusDropdownChange(e) {
    var dd_status = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.dd_status[""].stringInputs.value[0];
}
```

Notice that `e.formInput.dd_status` will also work, but the docs states its deprecated.

For more info:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#common_event_object
Under "Common event object" title.