# Can't find a Google Workspace apps script datetime picker "widgetID" necessary to get picker input value

Tags: google-apps-script, input, widget, datetimepicker

The following is a partial example of a date-time picker widget handler function. This handler simply logs a string representing the date-time chosen by the user in a date-time picker widget with the ID "myDateTimePickerWidgetID":

```
function handleDateTimeChange(event) {
    var dateTimeInput =
      event.commonEventObject.formInputs["myDateTimePickerWidgetID"];
    var msSinceEpoch = dateTimeInput.msSinceEpoch;
    var hasDate = dateTimeInput.hasDate;
    var hasTime = dateTimeInput.hadTime;
    ...
```

I cannot find anywhere in the reference where to set or get this ID

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets#:~:text=The%20following%20is,%C2%A0%20%7D%0A%7D](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets#:%7E:text=The%20following%20is,%C2%A0%20%7D%0A%7D)

I have tried using the example "myDateTimePickerWidgetID".

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: it's been a little while since I've used the Cards Service, but if I recall, the "ID" you're looking for may be the field name you supplied in the constructor of the DateTimePicker widget using the setFieldName function.

EDIT
I found an older thread that clarifies the point: [In Google Apps Script action handler, how to get value of a selection input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271284/in-google-apps-script-action-handler-how-to-get-value-of-a-selection-input)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: @mbarrett I found an older thread that seems to indicate that it is the setFieldName key that should be used as the "widget ID". Link is in the edited answer.